# .htaccess redirect to subfolder

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I'm struggling to get a solution for redirecting all pages (or just .html pages) to subfolder and keep the .html file name.

I have .html site with lot of subfolders and would like to redirect all traffic to same subfolder - `/download/file-name.html`

For example my site is:
`www.mydomain.com/subfolder1/some-file-name.html` to be redirected to `www.mydomain.com/download/some-file-name.html`

`www.mydomain.com/subfolder2/another-file-name.html` to be redirected to `www.mydomain.com/download/another-file-name.html`

PS. I don`t want that the "old subfolder" appears after`/download/...`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your htaccess file :

```
 #Redirect subfolder1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder1/(.*)/?$ /download/$1 

 #Redirect subfolder2
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder2/(.*)/?$ /download/$1
```

EDIT

```
 #Redirect multiple subfolder
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ /download/$2
```

Comment: Thanks but i have ~500 subfolders. Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into a Notepad file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ www.mydomain.com/download/some-file-name.html [L]
```

Save this as `[space].htaccess` within `www.mydomain.com/subfolder1/`.

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your solutions. I ended up using the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ /download/$2
```